# Linux image package installation fails with error

Tags: apt

I tried to install *net-tools* in Ubuntu 19.04 and i got this error:

> installation linux image 5.0.0-25-generic package
>   post installation script sub-process return error
>   exit status 1
>   errors were encountered while processing:
>   linux image-5.0.0.25-Generic E:subprocess package /usr/bin/dpkg return an error code.

please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the complete output. "Error exit status 1" merely means that *some* subprocess somewhere failed, which is insufficient information to help you. The rest of the output will tell us exactly what failed, and (often) why.

Comment: Please click [edit] to add the facts to your question and reformat the text so it matches what you saw. Please also add the command you typed to run the command.  Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .